# Distributing colour swatch to IcosahedronGeometry faces

Tags: three.js

I have a IcosahedronGeometry and would like to distributed an array of three blue colours as evenly as possible on the IcosahedronGeometry faces so that most adjacent faces use a different colour from the array. I could change the array to have 4 colours if that will work better?

I just don't understand the math enough to know in what order the faces are applied to the IcosahedronGeometry.

I've tried something like:

```
var colours = [0x62a5dc, 0x4577b9, 0x2b2b5d];

for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) 
{
  if(i<5) geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( colours[0] );
  else if(i<10) geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( colours[1] );
  else geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( colours[2] );
}
```

but didn't have a great result

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the utility program http://threejs.org/examples/misc_uv_tests.html.

It shows the UV map, and from that you can see which faces share an edge.

Remember, it wraps. The face numbers wrap, too. In the image below, the face numbers on the right edge are 19 and 14.

three.js r.58

[image]